# CV bridge OpenCV4 error

Tags: cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Noetic
Ubuntu 20.04

When I include cv_bridge like this:

```
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
```

and then use:

```
catkin build <project_name>
```

I get this error:

```
/opt/ros/noetic/include/cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h:43:10: fatal error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory
   43 | #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
```

I installed the full version of Noetic.

Is there a way to fix this?

Am I missing any additional things in my CMake or xml file? All that I have added is the following:

```
  <build_depend>cv_bridge</build_depend>

target_link_libraries(Color ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
                        ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

As far asmy knowledge goed, Noetic comes with OpenCV4, while cv_bridge is trying to include Opencv2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386926/cv-bridge-opencv4-error/) by [Bender_From_Futurama](https://answers.ros.org/users/82310/bender_from_futurama/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-09-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-09-20**:
Did you include cv_bridge in your Cmake?

1. On `find_package`
2. On `catkin_package`

**Comment by [Bender_From_Futurama](https://answers.ros.org/users/82310/bender_from_futurama/) on 2021-09-20**:
Yes you are correct. I was missing it in `find_package`. My bad.
Although, im not sure if it should be added to `catkin_package`, as it gave me additional errors when added there.

Thanks Ranjit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you include cv_bridge in your Cmake?

1. On `find_package`
2. On `catkin_package`

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1